# How do you place controllers and related views in separate folders in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to group all my Controllers with related Views in separate folders. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Don't.
2. But if you must, write a custom ViewEngine to locate the views. I wrote a (now out of date) example [here](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2008/07/31/37827/). ViewLocator has since been renamed to ViewEngine.
3. See (1)

Update: If you actually meant you're looking for an "areas" feature, try [this](http://blog.codeville.net/2008/11/05/app-areas-in-aspnet-mvc-take-2/).

Comment: I think he means the same thing as areas in monorail, which there is nothing wrong with so I have no idea why you say don't.

Comment: Areas don't work that way; perhaps it's what he really meant, though. See http://blog.codeville.net/2008/11/05/app-areas-in-aspnet-mvc-take-2/ for a good design for that.

Comment: I definitely meant the concept of Areas highlighted by Phil Haack.

Comment: Paco, Views shouldn't know about Controllers, so they should be in different namespaces, and hence different folders.

Comment: But views shouldn't know about each other too.

Comment: Um, true, though I've never actually seen anyone have a problem with that. Making controller<->view dependencies incorrect is *common*, though.

Comment: My views depend on controller because I use Html.ActionLink or Html.BeginForm. I don't understand what's bad about that.

Comment: That isn't a dependency. That's a string. Dependencies are different.

Comment: I consider something depending on something else a dependency. A form is posted to a specific controller action and it doesn't matter if a string or generic with lambda is used.

Comment: I'm not sure yet if I want to create a directory with controller/viewmodel/view or a directory per type like the default

Comment: My $0.02: Use the default unless you have a *really* good reason not to. About dependencies: I think we'll just have to disagree on that.